# boto python for SNS and SQS - Are the methods synchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I am doing integration testing for a project. Part of the test case involves the follow steps:

1. Create a SQS queue X
2. Subscribe to SNS topic Y
3. Check if X exists
4. Check if X is subscribed to Y
5. Unsubscribed X from Y
6. Check if X is unsubscribed to Y
7. Delete X
8. Check if X is non-existent

My test case generally runs fine up to the check at Step 6 then it fails.

I am using sns.get_all_subscriptions_by_topic() to check for the existence of subscription and apparently, I can still find X being subscribed to Y at this point. So this makes me wonder if the entire library is asynchronous. If so, I am not sure if I can easily do integration testing with it.

Unfortunately, the [boto API page](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/sns.html) doesn't say anything about synchrony.

Comment: Yeah, its not really boto its AWS.  Many of these operations are eventually consistent simply because of the enormous scale of AWS.  The boto calls are waiting for responses from the service before returning but that response does not mean that the server-side operation is complete.

Comment: Thanks guys. Can one of you post this as an answer so I can give it the check mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not have anything to do with boto - a lot of the AWS methods themselves are asynchronous and eventually consistent.

It doesn't appear to be documented, but I've seen asynchronous behavior on several SQS methods (e.g., queue purge) in the past.